# Trying to get property of non-object error when user doesn't have followers

Tags: php, laravel

I get the following error, whenever i go to a user profile page and the user doesn't have followers.*I am using [laravel follow](https://github.com/overtrue/laravel-follow)*

> Trying to get property of non-object
>           $user->followers->get();

When a user does have followers it shows the followers with no errors.

**MyFollow.php**

```
class MyFollow extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes, CanFollow, CanBeFollowed;

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'followable_id'
    ];

    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $table = 'followables';

    public function followers()
    {
        $user = User::find($this->user_id); 

        $user->followers->get();


    }



}
```

**UserController.php**

```
public function getProfile($user)
{  
        $user = User::with(['posts.likes' => function($query) {
                            $query->whereNull('deleted_at');
                        }])
                      ->where('name','=', $user)

                      ->with(['follow' => function($query) {

                            $query->with('followers');

                       }])->first();


        if(!$user){
            return redirect('404');
        }

        return view ('profile')->withUser($user);
}
```

**Profile.blade.php**

```
            @foreach($user->followers as $use)
                    @isset($use->name)
                    <ul>

                        <li>{{$use->name}}</li>
                     @endisset
                    </ul>



            @endforeach
```

**User.php**

```
  public function follow()
    {   
        return $this->hasMany('App\MyFollow');
    }
```

Comment: where is your relationship with user and follower ?

Comment: i just updated it.

Comment: then why are you adding `followers` in `MyFollow` model ?

Comment: its just a name for the function.

Comment: ok let me change in my answer

Comment: `public function follow() { ... }`, should that not be `public function followers() { ... }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MyFollow Model**

```
class MyFollow extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes, CanFollow, CanBeFollowed;

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'followable_id'
    ];

    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $table = 'followables';

    public function follower()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'followable_id');
    }
}
```

**change in controller**

```
public function getProfile($user)
{  
        $user = User::with(['posts.likes' => function($query) {
                            $query->whereNull('deleted_at');
                        }, 'follow','follow.follower'])
                      ->where('name','=', $user)->first();


        if(!$user){
            return redirect('404');
        }

        return view ('profile')->with('user', $user);
}
```

**View**

```
@foreach($user->follow as $follow)
     <ul>
        @if($follow->follower)
           <li>{{$follow->follower->name}}</li>
        @endif
    </ul>
@endforeach
```

Comment: let me give this a go.

Comment: i get `Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on null`

Comment: it seems `followers` is your relationship name, load it with eager loading

Comment: it still didn't work, i made an update to the post to show the profile page

Comment: i have updated answer, you need to change in `MyFollow` model, controller and in view try it

Comment: let me give this a go, thank you so much for your help.

Comment: interesting, im still getting this `Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on null`

Comment: did you change all model, controller and view ?

Comment: Yes, maybe i should do an artisan migrate:reset ?

Comment: there was a mistake in controller code, there was 2 with, fix it, change it and then try

Comment: i just tried it, i still get `Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on null`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174538/discussion-between-rkj-and-barnowl).

Answer (score 0):

So, just do a sanity check before returning a value.

```
public function followers()
{
    $user = User::find($this->user_id); 
    if ($user->followers) 
    { 
        return $user->followers->get(); 
    } else {  
        return "No Followers"; 
    }
}
```

Depending on how followers is constructed, you may need `$user->followers->count()`

Comment: let me give this a go.

Comment: it still shows Trying to get property of non-object. `if ($user->followers)`